# Timer script couting backwards before starting with zero

Tags: javascript, centos6, jboss6.x

timer.js counts the number of seconds and minutes a user is performing an action in a jsf form. Had no issues until we moved the app from 1 server to another (same base environment).

Issue starts with the timer starting at 24 minutes instead of 0.  Realizing, the server time was off by 24 minutes, I used ntpd corrected the time issue and the hardware clock was also corrected.  Now, timer.js counts backwards before counting from zero:

e.g. 01:0-1:0-54...01:0-1:0-53.....00:00:00....00:00:01 etc...

Why would it count backwards before starting at 00:00:00 (as it normally did)?

This is a really weird one for me and I apologize if I'm not too clear here.  Just trying to get some ideas on where to look.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You want us to guess without seeing a single line of code?  Good questions about specific problems with code must include the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

could it be that your server time is still off, but instead of ahead it is now behind? so when it counts backwards it's still a difference of time, but negative?

Comment: it is definitely with the time.  I've been adjusting it and currently it starts off at 41 seconds instead of counting down. Not sure how to sync it appropriately with the application but then again, should I have to?

Comment: Also, it may have something to do with the web server.  I see where others have restarted their web servers and noticed the difference.